# check if user has a new release note and notify him

Tags: django, django-sessions, django-notification

I want to find a simple way to notify users about a new release note without using django-notifications or adding a relation between user and release notes table in the database, using something like a flag that returns true once a new release note is added but i don't know if its possible to use session to check if user has already seen the release note or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are probably not a good solution for your problem:

1. Depending on your session backend, accessing sessions outside of a request is hard (DB backend) or downright impossible (cookie backend).
2. When a user logs out, the session is lost.
3. A user can have multiple sessions.

If you are fine with users seeing release notes multiple times, storing the date/id of the last release note seen in the session could work.

The most reliable approach is a `ReleaseNoteHistory` table where you store either the date of or a reference to the last release note the user has seen.

Comment: I think storing the date/id of the last release note seen in the session would be good because users are able to see release notes multiple times, but from (2.) if i logout and i login again with the same user i will have new session and the same notification in this case ... somehow users needs to be linked to this last release note?